# C# parse timestampwith format "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:SS.ms"

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I wanted to format a string to dateTime with the format

```
"yyyyMMdd HH:mm:SS.ms"
```

I tried doing `"yyyyMMdd HH:mm:SS"` as the string format for `ParseExact` but it doesn't recognise it. Also no clue how to include the milliseconds as well

any assistance?

Comment: Did you read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)?

Comment: And a simple Google search of *string format datetime* #1 results leads me to my favorite http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Comment: yeah thanks guys, sorry i did figure it out after you put that Jon. I really should have done a deeper search but its working nicely now :) thanks all!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

From the [custom date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) page, you use `ss` for seconds, and `FFF` for milliseconds:

```
"yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.FFF"
```

or

```
"yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.fff"
```

(Use the first if trailing 0s are suppressed, the second otherwise.)