# How to search timestamp using Datetimepicker

Tags: sql

I want to search timestamp using datetimepicker . I'm using SQL SERVER,
I tried this syntax but no luck, no error but no result

```
        DataTable dt2;
        SqlDataAdapter adpt2;

        DateTime datetime = dateTimePicker1.Value;

        adpt2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM itf_Attendance WHERE Timestamp=@timestamp", con_string);
        adpt2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timestamp", datetime);
        dt2 = new DataTable();
        adpt2.Fill(dt2);
        datagridview1.DataSource = dt2;
```

Somebody help , thank you.

Timestamp format: 2021-06-02 09:15:08.630

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set DateTimePicker's format as per your Timestamp format: 2021-06-02 09:15:08.630

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.FFF"; --Use FFF if trailing 0s need to be suppressed, or fff
--Also, hh is for 12-hr clock; if you want 24-hr format, use HH
```

Refer these links for more info - [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9902620/7060775) , [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Sure, please accept this as answer if this sovled your problem.